# VolleyError NetworkResponse is null

Tags: php, android, android-volley

Not new to android but new to Volley Library.
I am trying to send a stringRequest to server(of type POST) to update and retrieve rows. After that I am trying to get Json response out of it.

php code is working fine. Tested with the html form already.

problem :
VolleyError is returning null.
when trying to getMessage() it is returning null and even I cant print Networkstatus code.

following is the stringRequest code...

```
/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String vehicle_no, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String vehicle_no = user.getString("vehicle_no");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name,vehicle_no, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("vehicle_no", vehicle_no);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    Log.d(TAG, "string req: " + strReq.toString());
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

And this is the log:

```
01-31 11:30:37.407 14868-14868/csi_research_wing.vehicle D/LoginActivity: string req: [ ] http://192.168.0.101/android_login_api/login.php 0x85adf655 NORMAL null
01-31 11:30:45.035 14868-14868/csi_research_wing.vehicle E/LoginActivity: Login Error: null
01-31 11:30:45.036 14868-14868/csi_research_wing.vehicle D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-31 11:30:45.039 14868-14868/csi_research_wing.vehicle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: csi_research_wing.vehicle, PID: 14868
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.statusCode' on a null object reference
at csi_research_wing.vehicle.activity.LoginActivity$5.onErrorResponse(LoginActivity.java:187)
at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:524)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: put your response here so we can help you.

Comment: {"error":false,"user":{"name":"maok","vehicle_no":"Mousesds","created_at":"2016-01-31 10:25:18"}} this is one of the Responses...

Comment: Give me an log like
Log.e(TAG, "Login Error code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);

Answer (score 0):

**401 Not Supported by Volley**
It turns out that it is impossible to guarantee that error.networkResponse is non-null without modifying Google Volley code because of a bug in Volley that throws the Exception NoConnectionError for Http Status Code 401 (HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) in BasicNetwork.java (134) prior to setting the value of networkResponse.

**Work-Around**

Instead of fixing the Volley code, our solution in this case was to modify the Web Service API to send Http Error Code 403 (HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) for the particular case in question.

For this Http Status Code, the value of error.networkResponse is non-null in the Volley error handler: public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error). And, error.networkResponse.httpStatusCode correctly returns HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN.

**Other-Suggestions**

Rperryng's suggestion of extending the Request class may have provided a solution, and is a creative and excellent idea. Thank you very much for the detailed example. I found the optimal solution for our case is to use the work-around because we are fortunate enough to have control of the web services API.

I might opt for fixing the Volley code in one location within BasicNetwork.java if I did not have access to making a simple change at the server.

Comment: I didnt understand what u are trying to say... will you please explain me the workaround in simple words...

Comment: simply i want to say 401 Not Supported by Volley.

Comment: Then what can I do? plz help me with this. Coz I am facing this problem from last 3 days and tomorrow I want to submit this project. This project was built 3 months before. It was working fine that time and now it is showing me errors....

Comment: you have just copied the response of another question, that is the reason of the downvote.